# HTTP instance has no attribute getresponse Error on Python 2.6

Tags: python, http

I was trying to do some jsonrpc calls using python. However, since the api calls need cookies, so that I create my own transport class which will be used by the jsonrpclib. This works totally fine with latest 2.7 python. However, when I try to run it on the python 2.6.6, it complains that "HTTP instance has no attribute getresponse"

Code

```
class TransportMixIn(object):
    """ Just extends the XMLRPC transport where necessary. """
    user_agent = jsonrpclib.config.user_agent
    # for Python 2.7 support
    _connection = None

    def send_content(self, connection, request_body):
        connection.putheader("Content-Type", "application/json-rpc")
        connection.putheader("Content-Length", str(len(request_body)))

        if cookie != None :
            connection.putheader("Cookie",cookie)

        connection.endheaders()
        if request_body:
            connection.send(request_body)


    def getparser(self):
        target = JSONTarget()
        return JSONParser(target), target

    def request(self, host, handler, request_body, verbose=False):
        # issue XML-RPC request
        self.verbose = verbose


        try:
            h=self.make_connection(host)
            if verbose:
                h.set_debuglevel(1)

            self.send_request(h,handler,request_body)
            self.send_host(h,host)
            self.send_user_agent(h)
            self.send_content(h,request_body)
            **resp = h.getresponse()**
            if resp.status == 200:
                self.verbose = verbose
                global cookie 
                cookie = resp.getheader('set-cookie')
                return self.parse_response(resp)

        except xmlrpclib.Fault:
            raise
        except Exception:
            #All unexpected errors leave connection in
            # a strange state, so we clear it.
            self.close()
            raise

        #We got an error response.
        #Discard any response data and raise exception
        if resp.getheader("content-length", ""):
            resp.read()
        raise xmlrpclib.ProtocolError(
            host + handler,
            resp.status, resp.reason,
            dict(resp.getheaders())
            )



class Transport(TransportMixIn, XMLTransport):
    pass

class SafeTransport(TransportMixIn, XMLSafeTransport):
    pass
```

The error occurs at the line where resp=h.getresponse()

Any ideas??
Btw, is python such a language that code will be easily messed up when run on different versions? Such wired behaviour has occurred to me multiple times.

Comment: What is the type of `h`?  I don't see an implementation for `self.make_connection`.  Are you sure that that method exists in Python 2.6?  It's possible that that method was added later -- Python 2.6 is pretty old.

Comment: that should use the make_connection method in XMLTransport, and both python version uses the same version of the xmlrpclib module. So I guess they should have the same implementation? But I checked the type of h in python 2.7, it seems to be a httplib.HTTPConnection, but in 2.6 it is a httplib.HTTP.

Comment: I think you answered your question in your commment @user3354832

Comment: @BurhanKhalid What could be the root of the problem? xmlrpclib have the same versions among the two computers but why their call stack are different? How could I fix this problem? For the computer running python 2.6, I am not allowed to do any update on it.